# What was the reason of "access denied" exception while executing Runtime.exec() on Android?

Tags: android, permissions, runtime.exec

I have native executables compiled for Android and they are located in `/data/data/my.app.package` so I believe app is able to execute executables there.

Unfortunately `Runtime.exec()` causes an *"access denied"* exception. How can I know what object (path, file, etc) executable was trying to get access to? App reads files in `/data/data/my.app.package` and write files there.

No debug messages are in the log, the device is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that unzipping using Java Zip API does not save flags so files were not marked as executables. used `chmod 0755 (file)` to fix it